# AngularJS Directive Two data binding - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

So I have a two way data binding which I do not understand why it is not working, it does not update:

```
angular.module('core').directive('collapseNavOnClick', [
function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            collapseNavOnClick: '=',
            isCollapsed: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.isCollapsed);
            console.log(scope.collapseNavOnClick);
            elm.on('click', function() {
                console.log(scope.collapseNavOnClick);
                console.log(scope.isCollapsed);
            });

        }
    };
}
]);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<section data-ng-controller="HomeController" data-ng-init="init()" collapse-nav-on-click="isCollapsed" is-collapsed="isCollapsed">
```

And my controller (HeaderMenu is a service):

```
angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope','HeaderMenu',
    function($scope, HeaderMenu) {
        $scope.isCollapsed = HeaderMenu.isCollapsed;
```

So the problem is, when I do the 'clicks' and the isCollapsed has changed, it is not being updated on the directive, why?

The 'isCollapsed' value is changed by the controller, more specifically there is a controller function triggered by a ng-click that changes 'isCollapsed'.

I can log the value of the isCollapsed in the controller and see that it has changed however the directive does not get the updated value.

**More clarification:**

So a bit more info, I have an ng-click somewhere else:

What this does is changes the isCollapsed value, more specifically it pops open a menu.

Now what I want to do, when the body element is clicked, I want to hide that menu but I need to check if the menu is not already collapsed so I need to read the value of 'isCollapsed'. Hence I have the directive with an 'on click' event.

So what I need is, upon clicking the 'body' element, read the current value of 'isCollapsed' and take action.

**UPDATE:**

I've narrowed it down to the root problem:

$scope.isCollapsed =  HeaderMenu.isCollapsed;

That line doesn't actually sync with the HeaderMenu service, I should have assigned the whole object not just a field. Completely oversaw this.

Comment: Your directive, as written, is just a no-op.  When the element is clicked, do you intend to change the value of isCollapsed?

Comment: no, I just want to read the current state and take action based on it. The above is just a trimmed down version, i.e I took out the logic that tries to do something based on the current value. The console.log shows it is not updating.

Comment: What changes isCollapsed, then? And where?

Comment: I clarified a bit more on the question.

Comment: You probably will have to watch the value of isCollapsed using $watch.

Comment: I posted an answer I'm pretty sure will help, but it would be good to know what element has ng-click on it

Comment: Ah yes let me clarify a bit more, I can see it probably wasn't fully clear

Answer (score 0):

From your question, an ng-click somewhere triggers an isCollapsed change.  You want to monitor for that change.

You are currently doing this in your directive by listening for the click that causes the change with:

```
elm.on('click', function() {
    console.log(scope.collapseNavOnClick);
    console.log(scope.isCollapsed);
});
```

When this is run, it is entirely possible that ng-click has not yet run depending on where the clicked element is in the html hierarchy. What you really want to do is:

```
scope.$watch('isCollapsed', function() {
    console.log(scope.isCollapsed);
});
```

If you need to watch for body clicks, do that in your directive.  Also, you should use $scope.$apply

```
$('body').on('click', function() {
    scope.$apply(function(){
        console.log(scope.collapseNavOnClick);
        console.log(scope.isCollapsed);
    });
});
```

Comment: I've clarified what I wanted to do, I don't think I could use scope.$watch as I specifically need the trigger to happen upon the body element being clicked only.

Comment: Doesn't the elem.on('click') already watch for body clicks? My body click event does fire, however the problem is that isCollapsed is not updated. My directive will never modify 'isCollapsed' it just needs to know what the current value is when the body is clicked.

Comment: Does elem.click() fire even on clicks that are outside the element but inside the body?  At this point I'd suggest building a Plunker that reproduces your problem.

Comment: This is actually a close reproduction of the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/pierreduc/s9vjp2nk/6/ from the other answer, I can re-modify this to what I have (i.e. using scope not attrs) but the problem is the same, the variables don't update.

Comment: Wrong URL, this one: https://jsfiddle.net/s9vjp2nk/8/ but this works! but my own code doesn't.... hmm I'm going to close this of and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

you create a new scope with your directive. You can access the controller scope from the directive, but the controller can't access the directive's scope. Set scope to false, and assign the variables in link

```
angular.module('core').directive('collapseNavOnClick', [
function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.isCollapsed = attrs['collapseNavOnClick'];
            scope.collapseNavOnClick = attrs['isCollapsed '];
            console.log(scope.isCollapsed);
            console.log(scope.collapseNavOnClick);
            elm.on('click', function() {
                console.log(scope.collapseNavOnClick);
                console.log(scope.isCollapsed);
            });

        }
    };
}
]);
```

Comment: sadly this doesn't work for me and I'm not sure how it would since I'm not using two data binding from the '=' operator.

Comment: Did you try it? https://jsfiddle.net/pierreduc/s9vjp2nk/6/ 

You have to press the click within the 5 seconds, and then after 5 seconds click it again.. in the console you can see 3 different values for each scope variable

Comment: I did, try this, I've updated it with what I want to achieve, after the first click, no updates: https://jsfiddle.net/pierreduc/s9vjp2nk/6/

Comment: Sorry forgot to update url but here is what I am trying to achieve with what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/s9vjp2nk/7/

Comment: replace `$scope.isCollapsed != $scope.isCollapsed` with `$scope.isCollapsed = !$scope.isCollapsed` and you are good to go ;) Works for me at least.. https://jsfiddle.net/pierreduc/s9vjp2nk/10/

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to update on what the issue I had was and it was a really simple one that I overlooked.

A common issue of sharing a variable in a service object is not to give the variable itself but the Object containing it.

i.e. my problem was this:

```
$scope.isCollapsed = HeaderMenu.isCollapsed.
```

Instead I should have done:

```
$scope.headMenu = HeaderMenu;
```

and then simply do this on all my code, including directive:

```
$scope.headerMenu.isCollapsed = true;
```

I think many of us already know this, we just forget about it sometimes!